# sonar unable to process valgrind report

Tags: sonarqube, valgrind, sonar-runner

sonar-runner v2.4
sonarQube v4.3
wenns' CXX community plugin v0.9.1

I am trying to run sonar-runner to read in valgrind report but it would not work.

Upon sonar-runner's execution, plugin prove it is capable of reading in valgrind report as shown below;

```
04:52:10.044 DEBUG - Sensors : QProfileSensor -> CpdSensor -> CxxSquidSensor -> CxxRatsSensor -> CxxXunitSensor -> CxxCoverageSensor -> CxxCppCheckSensor -> CxxPCLintSensor -> CxxVeraxxSensor -> CxxValgrindSensor -> InitialOpenIssuesSensor -> ProfileEventsSensor -> ProjectLinksSensor -> VersionEventsSensor -> FileHashSensor
```

However, at the valgrind sensor what I see is;

```
04:52:11.820 INFO  - Sensor CxxValgrindSensor...
04:52:11.820 DEBUG - Using pattern 'valgrind-result.xml' to find reports
04:52:11.820 INFO  - Processing report '/home/*********/sonar_testing/sonarTestingSample/./valgrind-result.xml'
04:52:11.834 WARN  - Cannot find a project file to assign the valgrind error '110 bytes in 10 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1

0x4A05FDE: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
0x400639: IssueError(int) (in /home/*********/sonar_testing/sonarTestingSample/out)
0x400613: valgrindIssue() (in /home/*********/sonar_testing/sonarTestingSample/out)
0x4005EC: main (in /home/*********/sonar_testing/sonarTestingSample/out)
' to
04:52:11.834 INFO  - Sensor CxxValgrindSensor done: 14 ms
```

What does it mean ?
What am I doing wrong?

command I used for valgrind:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --xml=yes --xml-file=valgrind-result.xml ./out
```

Answer (score 0):

please see the follow link https://github.com/wenns/sonar-cxx/issues/258  that maybe help. check your valgrind version. this is a valgrind compatible problem